# App service plans file system storage limit exceeded 500GB

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We are using 9 functions apps with individual app service plan for each. 8 out of the 9 plans are standard plans which uses 50GB storage and 1 premium plan which has 250GB as file storage. Now we are trying to deploy new function app with new app service plan but we are getting error in devops like "storage usage quota exceeded 500GB". Can we increase this size limit or any other solution for it?[image: error image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, and definitely do not take a picture with a camera, that's just awful. Copy the original text to your question (+ format it either with quote or code format)

Comment: I can't post from my office laptop as it was against rules that's why I taken picture. Regarding the text typing part I tought, it would be better if i input an image so that people can understand better and can respond quickly. However thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It's against the rules to take a screenshot, but it's allowed to do the same thing with camera? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: While taking screenshot all my system and environment details are captured. But now in this picture you can't see anything other than error. That's the difference. Stock overflow sign was blocked by company monitoring policy settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits), the storage limit is the total content size across all apps in the same App service plan. The total content size of all apps across all App service plans in a single resource group and region cannot exceed 500 GB. The file system quota for App Service hosted apps is determined by the aggregate of App Service plans created in a region and resource group.

- If possible, check by deploying in another region of the app service plan in same resource group.
- Try clearing the unnecessary logs in the storage accounts associated with your function apps.

> Can we increase this size limit or any other solution for it?

**Other than Premium App Service Plan (250 GB), there is only one i.e., Isolated App Service Plan Provides 1 TB of Storage.**

To get more information about Isolated App Service Plan, visit this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

Also, If any issues in raising the storage limit, please raise a request to Microsoft support.